# EFI duplicate entries, start from efi doesn't work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, arch-linux, uefi

my UEFI entries dupplicate:

```
arch
ATAPI CD0: ...
ATA HDD0: ...
arch
ATAPI CD0: ...
ATA HDD0: ...
```

[image: screenshot UEFI]

Also if I want to boot from "arch" I can't, but it leads me back to the screen on the image.

I tried to get grub2 working with an Ubuntu-installation AND following the [arch linux guide](https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Anleitung_f%C3%BCr_Einsteiger).

Unfortunatelly I can't change the boot-option to bios, because I set a bios password which I don't remember anymore.

Can anyone tell me, what I am doing wront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate EFI boot entries are not unusual, and can result from any number of factors -- most commonly user error and bugs in OS programs intended to manage these things. That said, the fact that you're looking at three duplicates, two of which are not managed by the OS, suggests you may be looking at a firmware bug. Unless it causes real problems (and you've presented no evidence that it does), I'd ignore it.

As to your inability to boot Arch, that could be caused by any number of things, including Secure Boot problems, a damaged or buggy boot loader binary, a damaged EFI boot manager entry, missing or damaged components further on the boot chain (kernel, initrd file, etc.), and probably more. It's impossible to tell what's going wrong based on the information you've presented alone. I recommend you use my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a CD-R or USB flash drive to try to boot the installation. If you can get in, then you can attempt to re-install GRUB 2, or install something else in its place. You might also learn more by examining `efibootmgr -v` output to verify that your `arch` entries point to real boot loader files.